# Error import select view using MaterializeModule

Tags: angular, material-design, materialize

I have a project using select view. I imported MaterializeModule, and when I show data on select view, my layout broken.
There is my code:

```
<label>Language Select</label>
<select materialize="material_select"
       [materializeSelectOptions]="languages">
    <option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.id">{{language.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is my layout:
[image]

Comment: May I ask what Angular Materialize is? The [tag:angular-material] tag is meant for questions regarding the official Angular Material.

Comment: npm have support a library angular2-material. And I imported it into my project for purpose use select tag and multiple select

Comment: Are you sure? I tried looking on npm, but no such package exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-material

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize